# PostgreSQL: BRIN index not working properly (way too many lossy blocks)

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a large table into which I put rows in batches (each having approximately 1M rows, and 96 batches in total in the table right now), rows are inserted and certain number is also updated (but always the same batch id that is inserted) and whole batch is done in one transaction. I inserted the last batch and did query with where condition for that batch id (id_transformace  =1333). It took long to finish and it produced way too many lossy blocks. And I don't understand why, because only lossy blocks should be on the "edges" between the last and previous batch. I have this problem also with other tables where I insert rows in batches (and those do not even have update part in it). So could someone explain me what may be causing this problem. 
I have a little theory about autovacuum messing with physical spacing of the table but I do not have the full knowledge about it so I would be more than happy to hear insight from someone experienced.

**First try:**

```
"Limit  (cost=313.52..2349.39 rows=1000 width=207) (actual time=10390.834..10516.425 rows=1000 loops=1)"
"  Output: id, date_key_trainjr,..."
"  Buffers: shared hit=247024 read=46542"
"  I/O Timings: read=1554.586"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on reports.cdc_s5_gpps  (cost=313.52..2121240.53 rows=1041780 width=207) (actual time=10390.832..10516.180 rows=1000 loops=1)"
"        Output: id, date_key_trainjr, ..."
"        Recheck Cond: (cdc_s5_gpps.id_transformace = 1333)"
"        Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 5190343"
"        Heap Blocks: lossy=293516"
"        Buffers: shared hit=247024 read=46542"
"        I/O Timings: read=1554.586"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_cdc_s5_gpps_tran_br  (cost=0.00..53.08 rows=1185418 width=0) (actual time=17.484..17.484 rows=3512320 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (cdc_s5_gpps.id_transformace = 1333)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=50"
"Planning Time: 0.430 ms"
"Execution Time: 10516.683 ms"
```

**Second try:**

```
"Limit  (cost=313.52..2349.39 rows=1000 width=207) (actual time=40308.886..40459.645 rows=1000 loops=1)"
"  Output: id, date_key_trainjr,..."
"  Buffers: shared hit=11 read=293555"
"  I/O Timings: read=13316.262"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on reports.cdc_s5_gpps  (cost=313.52..2121240.53 rows=1041780 width=207) (actual time=40308.867..40459.386 rows=1000 loops=1)"
"        Output: id, date_key_trainjr,..."
"        Recheck Cond: (cdc_s5_gpps.id_transformace = 1333)"
"        Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 5190343"
"        Heap Blocks: lossy=293516"
"        Buffers: shared hit=11 read=293555"
"        I/O Timings: read=13316.262"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_cdc_s5_gpps_tran_br  (cost=0.00..53.08 rows=1185418 width=0) (actual time=23.991..23.991 rows=3512320 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (cdc_s5_gpps.id_transformace = 1333)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=11 read=39"
"              I/O Timings: read=5.167"
"Planning Time: 1.521 ms"
"Execution Time: 40460.087 ms"
```

**Index definition:**

```
CREATE INDEX index_cdc_s5_gpps_tran_br ON cdc_s5_gpps USING brin (id_transformace) WITH (pages_per_range='256')
```

Block(Page) size: 8192B
AVG row size 215B
Thus 9754 rows per BRIN range, and this should be the highest number (worst case scenario) of rows removed by index recheck not 5.1M

I also tried to make work memory bigger

```
set work_mem = '2 GB'
```

But no impact on number of lossy block and rows removed by recheck

```
Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 5190343
Heap Blocks: lossy=293516
```

And I get the same numbers if I set work memory to smallest possible size (64kB) so it is not the issue of bitmap not fitting into work memory (I read about this in other stack discussions but it does not seems to be my case)

> PostgreSQL 11.8 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5
>   20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39), 64-bit

Answer (score 1):

UPDATEs, even in the same transaction as the INSERT, will leave holes behind in the table.  If the table ever gets vacuumed, then some future INSERT will fill those holes with out-of-sequence tuples, leading to a degraded BRIN index.  Can you do the updates before bulk loading, perhaps in a temp or staging table?

> And I don't understand why, because only lossy blocks should be on the "edges" between the last and previous batch

BRIN indexes only return lossy blocks.  That is all they are capable of.

Comment: I could do the update in a temp table, .....but I guess if I delete certain batch it will create the same problem, but would vacuum full help me in the case of deleting if I do it after delete before new insert?